# Where am I going wrong with this proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

For all integers $j$, $j > 2$, $j^2 + j - 6$ is composite.

Proof:

Factoring $j^2 + j - 6 = (j+3)(j-2)$

Since $j > 2$ and $(j+3) > 2$

$j+3$ is a factor of $j^2 + j - 6$

The issue I have is, since $j > 2$, the factor $(j-2)$ is going to equal $1$ for $j = 3$, which defies the definition of a composite integer, since both factors need to not equal $1$.

Am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: So do $j=3$ separately , and for the rest what you write works. $j+3$ and $j-2$ don't work, but $j^2+j-6 = 6$ for $j=3$ so it is composite.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Oh, so in the case for j = 3, plugging 3 in for 6 makes it composite? Can you explain why?

Comment: @THEmathlearner12 Because $2 \cdot 3 = 6$ so it is composite.

Comment: @THEmathlearner12 I see what you mean : see , if you have a question that says "prove this property holds for all elements of a certain set" then it is not a problem, if for different elements of the set, the proof technique is different. The factorization $j^2+j-6 = (j-2)(j+3)$ works for all $j > 3$. You should not be disappointed because it did not work with $3$, but you can handle the case $j=3$ separately by just seeing that $6$ is composite!

Comment: In other words, the proof at $j=3$ might seem odd because we are not providing a factorization via algebra, but that's because the obvious way of factorization does not work! So we need to handle such a case separately, but because it is just one number we can check if it is composite or not. If you really wanted to do algebra, then note that if $j=3$ then $6 = 2j$ ,so we have $j^2 + j -6 =j^2+j-2j = j^2-j = j(j-1)$, which then gives a good factorization (*works only at $j=3$*.) To summarize : *you are not wrong , but your answer is incomplete, and can be completed easily*.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Ohh I see. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @THEmathlearner12 I would like to write an answer. Can I copy-paste the last two paragraphs of mine?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon sure

Comment: @THEmathlearner12 Done. If you liked it, kindly up vote and accept. Do visit the site more often!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a question that says "prove this property holds for all elements of a certain set" then it is not a problem, if for different elements of the set, the proof technique is different. The factorization $j^2+j−6=(j−2)(j+3)$ works for all $j>3$. You should not be disappointed because it did not work with $3$, but you can handle the case $j=3$ separately by just seeing that $6$ is composite!

In other words, the proof at $j=3$ might seem odd because we are not providing a factorization via algebra, but that's because the obvious way of factorization does not work! So we need to handle such a case separately, but because it is just one number we can check if it is composite or not. If you really wanted to do algebra, then note that if $j=3$ then $6=2j$ ,so we have $j^2+j−6=j^2+j−2j=j^2−j=j(j−1)$, which then gives a good factorization (*works only at $\mathit{j=3}$*) To summarize : *you are not wrong , but your answer is incomplete, and can be completed easily*.